# Power BI Gauge Visuals

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple table with activities. I would like to monitor the performance of these activities using powerBI. I have a target column in percentages and Q1 scores also in percentages. How do I create a gauge and filter so that when I filter a given activity, I am able to see the percentage in the gauge. Or is there an alternative visual for the same?
Thanks and regards

I have tried the gauge visual and it is just picking the number of activities

Comment: Please share the table with a few sample rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.